# android emulator displays 4 screens

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i have problem with android emulator, when it executed it displays 4 screens.
i tried to make a a new device many times with different settings but the same problem appears.

[the problem details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCGTy.jpg)
http://s31.postimg.org/w9mfc2osb/nav10.jpg

i'm using:
eclipse 4.4.2
OS: Linux Debian jessie

Comment: In the AVD Manager, there should be a "Use Host GPU" option. Toggle that to the opposite of what you have been using, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare big thanks to you, it works.

Comment: If you get a chance, write up an answer describing what you changed it to. For me, on Ubuntu, I used to have to disable host GPU mode, though it has been behaving better more recently.

Answer (score 1):

the problem disappeared after using host GPU

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Ebx.jpg)

thanks @CommonsWare